# Add a closure to scrollToItem method of CollectionView

Tags: objective-c, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, closures

I have a Scroll to Top button which navigates to the 1st cell of the collectionView. Now i want to hide that Scroll To Top button after the work is completed. Please guide me how to do that.

Code :

```
@IBAction func backToTopClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.productCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    bBackToTop.isHidden = true
}
```

The above code is working but not every time. Sometimes i have to click twice to hide it. Therefore i want to add a closure to the methods which will notify about the completion of the task

Comment: Where are you unhiding the button again once it is hidden?

Comment: Check the size of you button. See if its small and not taking the taps properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.productCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
    bBackToTop.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to add DispatchQueue, since any code about UI should run on Main Thread

```
@IBAction func backToTopClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.productCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        bBackToTop.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. Yet i get same results. When i scroll to like 10-15 cells then its working but scrolling to 100th cell, it not working